# Relative extreme point of function $f(x,y)$

Tags: optimization, multivalued-functions

Can you please explain how to find relative extreme points of function $f(x,y)$ if I have restriction of the function? I know how to find local extreme point, but this is the first time I have to find relative extreme point.

Comment: That's  the whole theory of optimization started formally from Lagrange in 1750 and has been developed up to now .

Comment: General idea: find the partial derivatives, find where they equal zero.  These are your critical points in the interior of your region.  Test if they are extrema or saddle points using second derivative tests (look up the criteria for this test in your notes).  Next if you have a closed boundary, parameterize the boundary.  Find extrema relative to your parameters i.e. $f'(t) = 0.$  Finally, if your parameteization is not smooth, check the "corners" i.e. placed not differentable on the contour.